# why doesn't archlinux support partial updates?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

Partial update is not supported according to the wikipage:https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pacman

But in such a scenario:
the last version of package X has dependencies of package Y.
Y's version 1.0 - 1.3 are all okay for that version of X, for example.
now, I have the version 1.0 of Y installed, why must I update it to 1.3 to support package X?
Why shouldn't I only update X to the last version while leaving Y as 1.0 for saving network traffic and maintaining time?

It seems no data about version dependencies in pacman's pakcage database. why not add such information for feasible partial updates?

Answer (score 0):

You can update individual repos:

```
pacman -Sy -r <somerepo>
```

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/15561

Comment: That bug report is a feature request, it is not implemented.